# Flash-like event binding in SDL 2

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I've been working for a while with SDL and the PollEvent method and it always served me well. However, after playing a little but with Flash-based engines, i'm trying to create an event listener system similar to the one we have in Flash. I'm thinking of something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
GameObject object
object.addEventListener(MOUSE_CLICK, myClickCallback)
```

However, i'm not sure on how to make this work in an effective way. I could run PollEvent on every frame and then iterate through the entire list of GameObjects on my scene: if the event received on PollEvent is an X, call all listeners of X. However, this seems really slow. Is there a better approach? Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: There's lot's of techniques that you can use that can speed up your search since the game objects are grouped together around the event(unless it's a global event then you have to call all listeners anyway). Don't unnecessarily  if you have many game objects that you want to be able to select and it's drawing the objects are cheap then perhaps you can look at pixel picking.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a list of objects, for each Event. So when calling addEventListener, what you really are doing is `listener_list[MOUSE_CLICK].add(object)`

Then you only need to call each object's myClickCallback function.

Answer (score 0):

SDL2 has two functions that may help you achieve what you want without having to keep the list of listeners yourself (which is what Flash does behind the scenes anyway).

- http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddEventWatch
- http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetEventFilter

These are not direct replacements for the "add listener" mechanism though. Make sure you read the warnings in the documentation! If your app is multithreaded (and on Android it always is whether you like it or not), there's additional caveats to take care of.

Comment: The problem is that i still have to maintain a list of active scene objects and iterate over them. Seems too slow and... wrong. Or is this the normal approach?